# Javascript If versus Python if statements in While loop

Tags: javascript, python

I am having a hard time trying to port this Javascript code to Python. In Javascript the function can take two strings such as str1=123456, and str2=passwo. Then it will output something like p1a2s3s4w5o6

In python it just combines it. Someone please tell me how this could be done with if statements in python if even possible. Maybe I need to do it another way. Thanks for your help.

Python example

```
def merge(str1, str2):
    arr1 = str1.split();
    arr2 = str2.split();
    result = "";
    index1 = 0;
    index2 = 0;
    while ((index1 < len(arr1)) or (index2 < len(arr2))):
        if(index1 < len(arr1)):
            result += arr1[index1];
            print("part1")
            index1 = index1+1;
        if(index2 < len(arr2)):
            result += arr2[index2];
            index2 = index2+1;
    print(result);
    return result;
```

Javascript example

```
function merge(str1, str2){
    var arr1 = str1.split("");
    var arr2 = str2.split("");
    var result = "";
    var index1 = 0;
    var index2 = 0;
    while((index1 < arr1.length) || (index2 < arr2.length)){
        if(index1 < arr1.length){
            result += arr1[index1];
            index1++;
        }
        if(index2 < arr2.length){
            result += arr2[index2];
            index2++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In python no semicolumns are needed.

Comment: `str1.split()` returns a list of substrings of `str1` split on whitespace, so in your case a list of one string, like `['abcdef']`. Just iterate on `str1` directly instead of the unneeded `arr1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 provides direct typecasting of string into list using list()
and remove semicolons.

Use

```
    arr1 = list(str1)
    arr2 = list(str2)
```

instead of

```
    arr1 = str1.split();
    arr2 = str2.split();
```

entire code:

```
def merge(str1, str2):
    arr1 = list(str1)
    arr2 = list(str2)
    result = ""
    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0
    while ((index1 < len(arr1)) or (index2 < len(arr2))):
        if(index1 < len(arr1)):
            result += arr1[index1]
            print("part1")
            index1 = index1+1
        if(index2 < len(arr2)):
            result += arr2[index2]
            index2 = index2+1
    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: it's not the same, this is his bug.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
def merge(str1, str2):
    return "".join(x + y for x, y in zip(str(str1), str(str2)))

print(merge("passwo", 123456))
```

This prints:

```
p1a2s3s4w5o6
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in python you don't need semi-columns at the end of statement.
Second, when you split() string in python, it's split it by default from spaces,
so it's create for you list of 1 object. so you don't need to split because python string it's already array-like.

and this is your fixed code (i just delete the split and rename the parameters to be arr instead of str):

```
def merge(arr1, arr2):
    result = ""
    index1 = 0
    index2 = 0
    while ((index1 < len(arr1)) or (index2 < len(arr2))):
        if(index1 < len(arr1)):
            result += arr1[index1];
            print("part1")
            index1 = index1+1
        if(index2 < len(arr2)):
            result += arr2[index2];
            index2 = index2+1
    print(result)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If both strings have the same length, you could replace the whole function by list comprehension:

```
result = "".join([f"{str2[ind]}{str1[ind]}" for ind in range(len(str1))])
```

As a function:

```
def merge(str1, str2):
    return "".join([f"{str2[ind]}{str1[ind]}" for ind in range(len(str1))])
```

Comment: use `zip` here, don't loop over the indices